# methods for dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on creating a web app that allows users to create a front end theme for a website; I'm mostly doing this to better my JS skills.

What I'm doing in the code below is creating "boxes" that span the width of the page, and I want to allow the user to edit each individual box.

The issue I'm facing is I can select the class/id that the user clicked along with the div I have set up for all the elements that the user wants; however I cannot seem to attach any DOM methods onto the object.

Errors are Uncaught TypeError: Object editBoxes has no method 'innerHTML' where 'innerHTML' can be any method. I've also tried Jquery's .html with the same result.

```
     for(i=1; i <= boxes; i++) {
                    box.innerHTML = box.innerHTML + [
                    "<div class = 'globalBox' id = 'box"+i+"'>",
                    "<div class = 'editDyBox'>edit this box <div class = 'editBoxes'></div<!--end edit boxes--></div>",
                    "</div><!--end box-->",   
                        ].join('');
                    }//end for
                 $(".globalBox").css("width", width+"%");

                     $(".editDyBox").click(function(){
                       var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                       var childClass = $(this).children().attr("class");
                       var customEdit = $(this).attr("class");
                       var editBoxForm = "<form class = 'editBoxForm'><input type = 'text' name = '"+parent+"' width = '100%'></form>";

                       childClass.innerHTML("hello")
                    });//end editdybox click
```

Thank you
-Art

Comment: There is no `editBoxes` variable in your source - Could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes a JSFIDDLE would be more easy to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) instead of your complex code?
It's designed for that.

Check out this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Z2Rz4/)

```
<div contenteditable="true">I'm the content</div>
```

It's supported by [**ALL**](http://caniuse.com/contenteditable) browsers (yeah, even IE5)

its a normal div, so it spans all the available width, and his content is editable. No JS or CSS nedded.

Answer (score 0):

This line returns a string, not a jQuery object

```
var childClass = $(this).children().attr("class");
```

So your variable childClass is going to just be a simple string object.  It will never have the method innerHTML.

Additionally, this will return only the first child's class value and not an array of class values.

Answer (score 0):

What about using one click handler per element?

```
var boxes = 3;
var $boxes = $("#boxes");

$.each(new Array(boxes), function () {

    var box = $("<div/>").appendTo($boxes),
        editBox = $("<div/>").text("edit this box").appendTo(box),
        editBoxForm = $("<div/>").appendTo(editBox);

    editBox.click(function () {
        editBoxForm.html("hello");
    });

});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy3YU/1)**

Answer (score -1):

Remove this

```
childClass.innerHTML("hello")
```

By this

```
$(this).children().innerHTML("hello");
```